# Unfortunately MyApp has stopped message, not sure how to solve

Tags: java, android

When debugging my android studio program using an emulator I suddenly started getting the following error as the app opened up.  It was working fine and then just started giving me this error.  I changed nothing in the code.

"Unfortunately MyApp has stopped"

If it helps below is where I started seeing errors in my logcat.

```
e07-17 18:58:20.744 1260-1296/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory
    07-17 18:58:20.744 1260-1296/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/misc_ce/0: No such file or directory
    07-17 18:58:20.744 1260-1296/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/media/0: No such file or directory
    07-17 18:58:23.142 1305-1305/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
    07-17 18:58:23.332 1305-1305/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
    07-17 18:58:25.169 1305-1321/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
    07-17 18:58:25.173 1350-1357/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
    07-17 13:58:26.662 1369-1369/? E/EmulatedCamera_Factory: 2 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
    07-17 13:58:26.662 1369-1369/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.0', error: 'Permission denied' (13)
    07-17 13:58:26.662 1369-1369/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.1', error: 'Permission denied' (13)
    07-17 13:58:26.662 1369-1369/? E/CameraService: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
    07-17 13:58:27.333 1368-1368/? E/RadioService: couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
    07-17 13:58:27.334 1368-1368/? E/SoundTriggerHwService: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
    07-17 13:58:29.248 1511-1511/? E/ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Neighbor Solicitation for fe80::d003:fdff:fe0f:d2c9 from radio0-peer to eth0: Cannot assign requested address
    07-17 13:58:29.315 1524-1524/? E/hostapd: Configuration file: /system/etc/simulated_hostapd.conf
    07-17 13:58:30.251 1511-1511/? E/ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Router Advertisement from eth0 to wlan1: Network is unreachable
    07-17 13:58:30.251 1511-1511/? E/ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Router Advertisement from eth0 to radio0-peer: Cannot assign requested address
    07-17 13:58:31.184 1367-1367/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    07-17 13:58:31.184 1367-1367/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    07-17 13:58:32.344 1367-1367/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
    07-17 13:58:32.421 1377-1377/? E/Netd: cannot find interface dummy0
    07-17 13:58:34.251 1511-1511/? E/ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Router Advertisement from eth0 to wlan1: Network is unreachable
    07-17 13:58:34.401 1367-1367/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
    07-17 13:58:34.472 1367-1367/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb
                                                 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
                                                     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)

                                                     at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
                                                     at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
                                                  Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)e
```

Comment: Rebuild the project after a clean or… Kill and restart the emulator or restart your computer… or post the correct FATAL exception that is causing `MyApp` to stop. (it’s not what you’ve pasted). *Or* -> do all of the above.

Comment: I've done most of what you've suggested, where shall I look to identify the FATAL exception (fyi, I'm new to app development in Android Studio.)...What's also odd about this is prior to getting the error I've successfully run the app, via the debugger, with out issue.  As well, I've not changed any code leading up to the error.  The error just randomly starts to occur.  To resolve I've had to create a new project and paste in my code, though eventually the resurfaces.

Comment: Apologies, was AFK overseas. Clean the log, run the app, when it crashes, search Logcat for the word “Fatal” ;) never fails ;)

Answer (score 1):

try to clean project

```
Build -> Clean
Build -> Rebuild Project
```